# Maximum number of comparisons to be performed to search a node that does not exist at all

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

For this binary search tree what is the maximum number of comparisons to be performed to search a node that does not exist at all.

[image]

Comment: It's the height of the tree in the worst case, 6 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of using a binary search tree to store data is that the maximum number of comparisons needed to determine whether an element exists or not is solely dependent on the maximum tree height. In the above case, the max tree height is 5, thus requiring up to 6 comparisons.

We usually want the binary search tree to be complete as this reduces the height of the tree and hence the number of comparisons necessary. The node that is chosen as the root determines how complete the binary search tree ends up being and hence the height of the resulting tree.

The beauty of the binary search tree derives from the implicit ordering of nodes i.e. values to the left of the node must be smaller and values to the right must be larger. When dealing with vanilla binary trees, the number of comparisons necessary to determine if an element exists in the tree or not is the number of nodes in the tree in the worst-case scenario due to the lack of ordering invariants.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you are looking for the number **n**, so for **each node** you will need to check if the number in a current node is **greater or smaller** than n so it will be constant. If you consider the worst-case it will he `const * number of comparisons`, so the worst case will be **for the lowest node**. So we can conclude it will be const * **height of the tree** - in this case, it is *6*